# Ember-simple-auth's sessionAuthenticationSucceeded does not fire

Tags: ember.js, ember-simple-auth

I want to use the `sessionAuthenticationSucceeded` action in my `applicationRoute`, but somehow it doesn't fire.

I checked and found that the trigger is being called [here](https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth/blob/f73c53bd3c6027454189af64205a1e860c291e9f/packages/ember-simple-auth/lib/simple-auth/session.js#L252), but it is not actually being triggered [here](https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth/blob/f73c53bd3c6027454189af64205a1e860c291e9f/packages/ember-simple-auth/lib/simple-auth/mixins/application-route-mixin.js#L137), neither is my custom `sessionAuthenticationSucceeded` action in the `applicationRoute`. (I also tried calling `_super` and commenting my custom action altogether, to make sure the default mixin action was not overwritten).

I'm using `ember-cli` `0.1.4` and `ember-simple-auth` `0.7.2` in combination with the standard oauth2 authenticator. I'm a running a canary build of ember combined with HTMLBars. Signin works fine except that the `sessionAuthenticationSucceeded` is not triggered (might also be case for other action that I'm not aware of).

application route:

```
// app/pods/application/route.js
import Ember from 'ember';
import SimpleAuthApplicationRouteMixin from 'simple-auth/mixins/application-route-mixin';

export default Ember.Route.extend(SimpleAuthApplicationRouteMixin);
```

controller:

```
// app/pods/signin/controller.js
import Ember from 'ember';
import LoginControllerMixin from 'simple-auth/mixins/login-controller-mixin';

export default Ember.Controller.extend(LoginControllerMixin, {
  authenticator: 'simple-auth-authenticator:oauth2-password-grant'
});
```

signin template:

```
// app/pods/signin/template.hbs
<form {{action 'authenticate' on='submit'}}>
  {{input value=identification class="form-control" placeholder='Enter your email address' type='text'}}
  {{input value=password  class="form-control"  placeholder='Enter Password' type='password'}}
  <button type="submit" class="btn">Log in</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you add more detail (configuration, used authenticator, authorizer etc., in which exact situation is the action not triggered)?

Comment: also you're probably using ember-cli 0.1.4 as that's the latest version?

Comment: I use the default setup as described in the docs. `SimpleAuthApplicationRouteMixin` `LoginControllerMixin` with `'simple-auth-authenticator:oauth2-password-grant'` as authenticator. Signing up works well. I do run a canary build of ember icw HTMLBars.

Comment: You really need to add as much detail as you can (code etc.) if you want people to help you. Also in what exact version is the action not triggered?

Comment: I understand marcoow, I added more detail. I was hoping that the fact that I reverted back to the default setup, combined with stating that the trigger was called, but never reached the action, would ring some sort of bell : )

Comment: Hm, looks good actually. Could you debug into the code here https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth/blob/master/packages/ember-simple-auth/lib/simple-auth/mixins/application-route-mixin.js#L90 and check that the action is actually being sent?

Comment: @marcoow, As stated in my original question, I checked if the action was being send (the `here` links, perhaps a little obfuscated: ), it did get triggered but not actually called. It turned out to be the `beforeModel` hook in my `applicatioRoute` which was overwritten without calling `this._super()`. Thanks anyway.